# Tool to create a visualization from existing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, visualization

I took over a project with existing MongoDB. I would like to get visual image (diagram etc) of the existing data. Obviously MongoDB is pretty different case compared to MySQL but I guess there is still something that can be visualized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really depends on your requirements for "visualization".  Typically most of the more interesting visual aspects of a diagram for a relational database are the high level relationships and integrity constraints (1:1, 1:many, primary key, foreign keys, etc).

MongoDB has *flexible* schema, in the sense that documents within a given collection do not have to comply with a predetermined format.  That does not mean that the underlying data cannot have some organization .. just that there is no single schema imposed on a collection (as would be the case in a traditional relational database).

In MongoDB, a lot of the interesting details to visualize will require analysis by inspecting some or all of the documents in a collection OR by reviewing the code.

#### Code Review

If your application is using an ODM (Object Document Mapper) such as [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) (Node.js) or [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) (Java), the application code may provide a quick and descriptive view of the intended schema (or at least the latest version of the intended schema). An appropriate language documentation tool such as `jsdoc` or `javadoc` may be helpful to generate a reasonable overview of your model classes. You will probably have to add some documentation annotations for best results.

#### Schema Analysis

Schema analysis is a more brute force approach which involves looking at the data in order to infer an observed schema. A common approach for this is to use [Map/Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/).

There are a few different [`mongo` shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) helpers that will give you an idea of the general structure of collections (eg. field/data types and their coverage in the source documents):

- [schema.js](http://skratchdot.com/projects/mongodb-schema/)
- [variety](https://github.com/variety/variety)

These aren't visual (in the graphical sense), but the schema analysis results do provide insight into the expected shape of the data and common variations.

#### Relationships

The MongoDB server does not have support for foreign key relationships, which removes a lot of potentially interesting visual annotations.

There are some different client driver approaches to creating [Database References (DBRefs)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/), but these are following usage conventions rather than a server feature. In order to determine relationships between collections using DBRefs, some or all of the documents in a collection would have to be scanned. Inference of relationships isn't supported by either `variety` or `schema.js` yet.

#### Content

To get a better idea of the actual content, you could try one of the [Admin UIs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/).

Answer (score 5):

You Can use [Mongo3](http://mongo3.com/) or [futon4mongo](https://github.com/sbellity/futon4mongo) and [MogoVue](http://www.mongovue.com/)  is best for this.

And whole documented list of tools are [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs).

Comment: you are looking for such thing or I misunderstood? :(

Comment: mongo3 is ftw for scaling!

Answer (score 1):

I have used mViewer which I found really simple and good.

A simple web-based Administration and Management Tool for MongoDB here is the link

https://github.com/Imaginea/mViewer