# How to generate simple schema from database in meteor

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor, database-schema, meteor-autoform

How can we generate a schema from the database in meteor app.
I want to generate multiple schemas from each database entry.

The DB used is Mongo DB.

This schema will be used later to generate a form.

I am using autoform to generate a form.

[1: http://autoform.meteor.com]

Comment: This answer on how to reverse engineer a mongodb schema might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386547/tool-to-create-a-visualization-from-existing-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small script that you can run in mongo to reverse engineer an existing (flat) collection.

```js
/*
**  SimpleSchema definition generator  
**  
**  This will reverse engineer a flat collection
**  only at this point. If you improve this,
**  please share: {"email-left": "timstew", "at":"@", "email-right": "gmail.com"} 
**                              
*/
var schemaName = "publisherSchema"; // Name you want to give to your simple schema
var collectionName = "publishers"; // mongodb collection name (not including 'db.')
var sampleID = "54c00f0d2b21500370a2e4c4"; // _id of a good representative document

// OK, that's all the info we need - Let's get started!
var message = eval("db." + collectionName + ".findOne({_id:\"" + sampleID +"\"})");
var count = 0;
// Hack because I can't figure out how to find out how many fields are in 
var numKeys = 0;
for(var key in message) {numKeys += 1}

var index = 0;
for (var key in message) {
    if (index == 0) {
        print(schemaName + " = new SimpleSchema({");
        }
    print("\t" + key + ": {");
    print("\t\ttype: " + toProper(eval("typeof db." + collectionName + ".findOne({_id:\"" + sampleID + "\"})." + key)) + ",");
    print("\t\tlabel: \"" +  toProper(key) + "\"");

    if (index == numKeys-1) {
        print("\t\t}");
        print("\t})");
    } else {
        print("\t\t},");
    }
    index += 1;
}

function toProper(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. MongoDB is a document database, which doesn't require a schema. All you need to do is [declare collections in Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection)
2. If you want to be strict about the document structure, check out https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2 (`meteor add aldeed:collection2`)

I've recently explained Meteor collections and schemas [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/7cce3ca0-2e7b-4603-90c5-570b646f0dd7/entry/meteor_part_3_collections?lang=en).

If you want to read the schema from a collection, you can simply access it via `collectionName.simpleSchema()`. For your purpose you can take this schema and convert it into your desired structure (or exclude certain configured fields).

Comment: I have to display all items of the object , can u give any eg?

Comment: Are you saying that I have to display the collection only?

Comment: Ah understand. Extended the answer. The last paragraph should point you in the right direction.

Comment: so if I have multiple schema should I save it in the same collection or make different collections?

Comment: If you're talking about converting a relational schema into a document schema it really depends on what you want to do with the data. The thinking behind document based databases is a lot different. In relational databases, I personally tend to spread my objects, where in document-based databases I only create collections for my root objects. Especially relationships are usually not stored in separate collections but as fields (1..1) or list of values (1..n, n..m).

Comment: I will activate only one schema at one time and make a form out of it